# Driven Harmonic Oscillation with Pre-Loaded Condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I hope I'm right here in that forum:

A simple harmonic driven undamped single mass oscillator is described by the equation of motion:
$$ \ddot{x}=-\frac{k}{m}x+\frac{A}{m}sin(\omega t) $$

I try to calculate the force over time driving the mass point with the amplitude $\textit{A}$ and frequency $\omega$ in a pre-loaded spring condition. The amplitude is smaller than the deflection $\textit{x}$ needed to pre-load the spring.
Can anybody guide me how to set up the equation of motion?

Thanks a lot.